# Iterating over container or range - problem with constness

Tags: c++, visual-c++, range-v3

I am trying to write a template function that will sum up all elements of some collection - specified either as a plain stl container, or as a ranges-v3's range. (The actual function, as shown below is a bit more generic) I thought this would work:

```
template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
std::pair<Ret, int> sum(const Range& range, Ret zero, Func extract) {
  using It = decltype(range.begin());
  Ret sum = zero;
  int numElements = 0;
  for (It it = range.begin(); it != range.end(); ++it) {
    sum += extract(*it);
    ++numElements;
  }
  return { sum, numElements };
}
```

This indeed works for STL elements, but not for ranges. This gives me a very long error:

```
<this file, at line 'using It'> error C2662: 'ranges::v3::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<ranges::v3::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::adaptor_cursor<std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>,ranges::v3::iter_transform_view<Rng,ranges::v3::indirected<Fun>>::adaptor<false>>>,ranges::v3::remove_if_view<ranges::v3::transform_view<Rng,Fun>,ranges::v3::logical_negate_<EnemyGroup::stepUpdate::<lambda_c582fb1297dce111c4572cef649d86b9>>>::adaptor>> ranges::v3::view_facade<Derived,ranges::v3::finite>::begin<Derived,false,0x0>(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Range' to 'ranges::v3::view_facade<Derived,ranges::v3::finite> &'
note: Conversion loses qualifiers
```

originally, I thought it was some deficiency of the vs2015 branch of ranges-v3. Without thinking much, I just hacked a quick walkaround:

```
template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
std::pair<Ret, int> sum(const Range& range, Ret zero, Func extract) {
  using It = decltype(const_cast<Range*>(&range)->begin());
  Ret sum = zero;
  int numElements = 0;
  for (It it = const_cast<Range*>(&range)->begin(); it != const_cast<Range*>(&range)->end(); ++it) {
    //sum += extract(std::as_const(*it)); (does not work either, converts to void)
    sum += extract(*it);
    ++numElements;
  }
  return { sum, numElements };
}
```

but with the newest MSVC version that just came out from preview, the master branch of ranges is now officially supported. Yet, the above error prevails.

- Is using range's objects as `const&` a wrong thing to do? I know these objects are lightweight and are easy to copy around, but using a const reference shouldn't hurt, or? On the other hand, if a concrete STL container is passed, I need it to be passed as `const&`
- If using `const&` is incorrect, is there some easy way to have a function work with both containers and ranges, without writing anything at the call site (e.g. invoking `view::all`)

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.9.3. Note, that before 15.9, `range-v3` in its master branch was not supported.

---

Since you are asking how exactly I call it. My actual code is complicated, but I reduced it down to this small example:

```
#include <set>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>

template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
std::pair<Ret, int> sum(const Range& range, Ret zero, Func extract) {
  using It = decltype(range.begin());
  Ret sum = zero;
  int numElements = 0;
  for (It it = range.begin(); it != range.end(); ++it) {
    sum += extract(*it);
    ++numElements;
  }
  return { sum, numElements };
}

int main() {
  std::set<int*> units;
  auto [vsum, num] = sum(
    units | ranges::v3::view::filter([](const int* eu) { return *eu>0; }),
    0,
    [](const int* eu) { return *eu/2; }
  );
}
```

This gives me the same conversion errors as above.

Comment: Does using `cbegin()` instead of `begin()` help?

Comment: Thought that too, but I quickly learnd that `'cbegin': is not a member of 'ranges::v3::remove_if_view.......`

Comment: Does free function `std::cbegin/ranges::cbegin` work?

Comment: Nope. `using It = decltype(ranges::v3::cbegin(range));` gives me `'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found`, followed by `error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type ranges::v3::_cbegin_::fn::operator ()(const R &&) noexcept(<expr>) const'`

Comment: Can you add which ranges-v3 header you include, the range you create and how you call your `sum` function with it? I tried `for (const auto& v : range) { sum += extract(v);` and that worked on my own range lib with a `const` range, but with the iterator, it didn't (can't explain why).

Comment: Can't tell you why this isn't working but another workaround could be to make the fucntion `template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
std::pair<Ret, int> sum(Range& range, Ret zero, Func extract) { code here }` and `template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
std::pair<Ret, int> sum(Range&& range, Ret zero, Func extract) { return sum(range, zerp, extract); }`

Comment: Simplification idea, you can lose the `It` type alias and just do `for ( auto it = ... `   This may magically fix your const problem as well.

Comment: I'd say that the problem is in your functor. Which one are you using? Note that `begin` applied to a `const Range` returns a `const_iterator` and a lambda taking an `auto &` may be problematic. I have just tested `std::cout << sum(view::reverse(view::iota(0u,100u)),0u,[](auto i) { return 2.0*i; }).first;` and in works fine under VS2015

Comment: @TedLyngmo  I provided a complete example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all ranges are `const`-iterable. That is, there are range types `T` for which `const T` is not a range. `filter` is the classic example: it needs to cache the value of the iterator returned from `begin` so that future calls are O(1) (See http://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter.view#6). Consequently, `begin` cannot be a `const` member function without violating the Standard Library policy that `const` members are callable from multiple threads without introducing data races.

As a consequence, `const Range&` isn't idiomatic for accepting general `Range` arguments as it was for accepting "container that I don't intend to modify." We recommend that functions that take `Range` arguments accept them by forwarding reference. If you alter your program to:

```
#include <set>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>

template <typename Range, typename Ret, typename Func>
std::pair<Ret, int> sum(Range&& range, Ret zero, Func extract) { // Note "Range&&"
  Ret sum = zero;
  int numElements = 0;
  for (auto&& e : range) {
    sum += extract(e);
    ++numElements;
  }
  return { sum, numElements };
}

int main() {
  std::set<int*> units;
  auto [vsum, num] = sum(
    units | ranges::v3::view::filter([](const int* eu) { return *eu>0; }),
    0,
    [](const int* eu) { return *eu/2; }
  );
}
```

It will compile and run correctly.